# Six-sided die rolling $n$ times

Tags: probability, proof-verification

**Problem**: A six-sided die is rolled $n$ times. Let $M$ be the smallest number of dots in some roll, and let $S$ be the greatest number of dots. Find $P(M=2,S=5)$ in terms of $n$.

**Hint**: It might be useful to determine first the following $P(M\geq 2, S\leq 5)$, $P(M\geq 3,S\leq 5)$, $P(M\geq 2,S\leq 4)$ and $P(M\geq 3,S\leq 4)$.

**My answer**: We'll use the hint. We see that $$P(M\geq 2, S\leq 5)=P(\{2,3,4,5\}\cap \{1,2,3,4,5\})=P(\{2,3,4,5\})=\left ( \frac{4}{6} \right )^{n}$$
$$P(M\geq 3,S\leq 5)=P(\{3,4,5\})=\left ( \frac{3}{6} \right )^{n}$$
$$P(M\geq 2,S\leq 4)=P(\{2,3,4\})=\left ( \frac{3}{6} \right )^{n}$$
$$P(M\geq 3,S\leq 4)=P(\{3,4\})=\left ( \frac{2}{6} \right )^{n}$$

(I am not sure about the notations above, so please let me know what notations are standard to use)

Notice that
\begin{align}
P(M\geq 2,S\leq 5)=P(M\geq 2,S= 5)+P(M\geq 2,S\leq 4)\\
P(M\geq 2,S= 5)=P(M= 2,S= 5)+P(M\geq 3,S= 5)\\
P(M\geq 3,S\leq 5)=P(M\geq 3,S\leq 4)+P(M\geq 3,S= 5)
\end{align}
so we have
\begin{align}
P(M= 2,S= 5)&=P(M\geq 2,S= 5)-P(M\geq 3,S= 5)\\
&=[P(M\geq 2,S\leq 5)-P(M\geq 2,S\leq 4)]\\
&\quad -[P(M\geq 3,S\leq 5)-P(M\geq 3,S\leq 4)]\\
&=\left [ \left ( \frac{4}{6} \right )^{n}-\left ( \frac{3}{6} \right )^{n} \right ]-\left [ \left ( \frac{3}{6} \right )^{n}-\left ( \frac{2}{6} \right )^{n} \right ].
\end{align}

Comment: Should be all right: I even made a simulation with 1000000 trials for $n=3$ and $n=4$, which confirms your result.

Comment: @Aretino Thanks. Do you know if I used the notations correctly?

Comment: Usually $P(\{2,3,4\})$ is used to denote the probability to obtain exactly those numbers, which is not the case here. I think you should use something like $P(x_n\in\{2,3,4\},\forall n)$.